# Calculating Average of Staff Between Dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I had a question answered on here brilliantly yesterday, and hopeful this can be answered as expertly.

I have a date table with list of dates, as you would expect.

I have a table of staff with unique ID, start date, end date included called Staffmaster.

There's a 1 to many relationship between date and Staffmaster tables.

After yesterday's answer, I can work out how many staff today, and how many staff on a filtered date as required. But How do I work out an average number of staff between two dates? Using the same example I had, let's say today and 31/10/2022.

It should be easy to do

```
Average Staff = ([current Employees]+[previous staff])/2
```

But this doesn't allow me to specify dates to use. So I tried to do it as follows:

If [Current Employees] is

```
Current Employees = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTx(
      FILTER(
        STAFFMASTER,
        STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date]<=max('Date'[Date]) &&
        (ISBLANK(staffmaster[End Date]) || staffmaster[End Date]>max('Date'[Date]))
      ),
      (STAFFMASTER[Unique Id])
    ),
    CROSSFILTER(STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date], 'Date'[Date], None)
  )
```

and
[previous staff] is

```
Previous Staff = 
  var minD = MIN('Date'[Date])
  var maxD = MAX('Date'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('STAFFMASTER'[Unique ID]),
    'STAFFMASTER'[Current Employment: Start Date] <= minD &&
    ( 'STAFFMASTER'[End Date] >= maxD || ISBLANK('STAFFMASTER'[End Date]) ),
    CROSSFILTER('Date'[Date], STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date], None)
  )
```

Then I tried to put these together to use.

```
Average Staff = 
VAR CurrentEmps = CALCULATE(COUNTx(FILTER(STAFFMASTER,STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date]<=max('Date'[Date]) && (ISBLANK(staffmaster[End Date]) || staffmaster[End Date]>max('Date'[Date]))),(STAFFMASTER[Unique Id])),CROSSFILTER(STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date],'Date'[Date],None))
VAR Employed = 
 var minD = MIN('Date'[Date])
  var maxD = MAX('Date'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('STAFFMASTER'[Unique ID]),
    'STAFFMASTER'[Current Employment: Start Date] <= minD &&
    ( 'STAFFMASTER'[End Date] >= maxD || ISBLANK('STAFFMASTER'[End Date]) ),
    CROSSFILTER('Date'[Date], STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date], None)
  )

RETURN
    (CurrentEmps + Employed) / 2
```

But I don't get the required result

Any suggestions or an alternative way to do this?

I expected to get the average staff between two filtered dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average between a selected date with Today's then:

```
Employed Staff Count = 
  var minD = MIN('Calendar'[Date])
  var maxD = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('STAFFMASTER'[Unique ID]),
    'STAFFMASTER'[Current Employment: Start Date] <= minD &&
    ( 'STAFFMASTER'[End Date] >= maxD || ISBLANK('STAFFMASTER'[End Date]) ),
    CROSSFILTER('Calendar'[Date], STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date], None)
  )

Employed Staff Count - Today =
  CALCULATE(
    [Employed Staff Count],
    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date] = TODAY() )
  )

Employed Staff Count - AVG = 
  DIVIDE(
    [Employed Staff Count] + [Employed Staff Count - Today],
    2
  )
```

And if you want the daily average across a selection of dates then:

```
Employed Staff Count - AVG Daily = 
  var tot = SUMX( VALUES('Calendar'[Date]), [Employed Staff Count] )
  var cnt = COUNTROWS( VALUES('Calendar'[Date]) )
  return DIVIDE( tot, cnt )
```

---

#### Supplemental

If you wanted to look at this at a Monthly (or weekly, or quarterly) grain and your `Calendar` date table has a column for that grain (eg column `Year-Month = FORMAT([Date], "yyyy-MM")`. Then the measure `[Employed Staff Count]` will still work but it will only give employee count of those who have been employed throughout that grain period.

If you wanted a measure for total employee count in that grain whether partial or fully employed in that grain, then you would need:

```
Employed Staff Count Partial = 
  var minD = MIN('Calendar'[Date])
  var maxD = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('STAFFMASTER'[Unique ID]),
    'STAFFMASTER'[Current Employment: Start Date] <= maxD &&
    ( 'STAFFMASTER'[End Date] >= minD || ISBLANK('STAFFMASTER'[End Date]) ),
    CROSSFILTER('Calendar'[Date], STAFFMASTER[Current Employment: Start Date], None)
  )
```

Note how the logic changes to startDate `<= maxD` and endDate `>= minDate`

Whether your want full or partial count, you can then have monthly avg like:

```
// fully employed for each month
Employed Staff Count - AVG Monthly = 
  var tot = SUMX( VALUES('Calendar'[Year-Month]), [Employed Staff Count] )
  var cnt = COUNTROWS( VALUES('Calendar'[Year-Month]) )
  return DIVIDE( tot, cnt )

// partially employed for each month
Employed Staff Count Partial - AVG Monthly = 
  var tot = SUMX( VALUES('Calendar'[Year-Month]), [Employed Staff Count Partial ] )
  var cnt = COUNTROWS( VALUES('Calendar'[Year-Month]) )
  return DIVIDE( tot, cnt )
```

Comment: Sam, thats brilliant. Everything here works perfect 
If I calculate terminated employees as 
Terminated Employees = 
VAR StartDate = MIN('Date'[Date]) 
VAR EndDate = MAX('Date'[Date])

RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(StaffMaster[Unique ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(StaffMaster),
            StaffMaster[End Date] >= StartDate &&  
            StaffMaster[End Date] <= EndDate
        ),
        ALL('Date')
    )

How do I get this to show attrition? 
Attrition = [Terminated Employees]/[Employed Staff Count - AVG]
is what I thought, but it calculates wrong

Comment: It would be `Attrition = DIVIDE([Employed Staff Count] - [Employed Staff Count - Today], [Employed Staff Count - AVG] )` , no?

Comment: Its not. 
Attrition the way I would calculate is normally 
The number of terminated people in a period
divided by
Average number of staff over that same period
Annoyingly i seem to be close to getting it right, I seem to get 18.8% but I should be getting 18.3%
I dont know, but I think its something to do with the fact the Terminated Employees Measure gets a filter applied "on or after a set date", whereas the Average Employee count you gave me is "on a set date"

Comment: For example there were 348 employees terminated on or after 31/10/22, and there are an average of 1910 staff over the period 31/10/22 - Today
Which should give 18.3% but i get 18.8% in the calculation

Comment: Sam, I got it. My problem was the calculation in the Terminated Employees measure was counting people whos termination date was in the future as well. 
I amended to this

Terminated Employees = 
VAR StartDate = MIN('Date'[Date]) 
VAR EndDate = TODAY()

RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(StaffMaster[Unique ID]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(StaffMaster),
            StaffMaster[End Date] >= StartDate &&  
            StaffMaster[End Date] <= EndDate
        ),
        ALL('Date')
    )

and it works perfectly